# Class tags not visible/executed on my website

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, themes

I bought a template from casethemes (https://demo.casethemes.net/consultio-finance2/) now while using same tags as their demo site i cant get the classes executed and shown as broken. Am i missing some libraries to integrate? Below are few classes arent working and showing broken images on my side but works fine on demo page.

```
<i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i>

<i class="fac fac-search"></i>

<i aria-hidden="true" class="flaticon flaticon-social-media"></i>

<i aria-hidden="true" class="flaticon flaticon-report"></i>
```

[On my website it is shown like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS42Z.png)

[On demo template it is shown as like this, you can check website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUGPT.png)

What could be the issue? Please help

Comment: Looks like you are missing some pictures in your source files or they are not referenced correctly. It's hard to tell when you are not providing the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

check if font-awesome is getting imported properly

Comment: you mean the library i am using to import font awesome? I am unable to find it within theme they gave to me I am checking header section to check if there's any but when i search for font aweseme i get a lot of search result which to check for the issue even i am not sure.

Comment: go to you  your webpage -> view page source -> search for font awesome , if it is getting imported properly it should be there or you will have to import it manually